# Форма авторизации Django не возвращает ошибки

Tags: django

Создал на тестовом сайте 2 формы - регистрация и авторизации. 
Например, если в форме регистрации пропустить какое то поле то отображается ошибка, что поле нужно заполнить.
Если же допустить ошибку в поле авторизации, то страница просто обновляется с обнулением полей.
Обе формы функционируют корректно.
Django 1.9.7

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from .models import Post
def auth(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form_auth = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        username, password = request.POST.get('username', ''), request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
    else:
        form_auth = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, "blog/auth.html", {'form_auth': form_auth})

def reg(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form_reg = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form_reg.is_valid():
            new_user = form_reg.save()
            return redirect('/auth/')
    else:
        form_reg = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, "blog/reg.html", {'form_reg': form_reg})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы форма сгенерировала список ошибок, надо запустить ее валидацию.
Во view регистрации у вас есть вызов метода формы is_valid(), который заполняет атрибут формы errors значениями.

Аутентификация происходит внутри формы AuthenticationForm.

```
def auth(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form_auth = AuthenticationForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
        if form_auth.is_valid():
            user = form_auth.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
    else:
        form_auth = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, "blog/auth.html", {'form_auth': form_auth})
```

Comment: При таком варианте даже авторизация перестала работать. Ошибки так же не появляются.

Comment: Более логично валидировать логин и пароль в форме. Там же происходит аутентификация пользователя, нет необходимости вызывать authenticate во view. Пожалуйста, выложите template, может, в нем проблема.

Comment: Можно посмотреть, что лежит в form_auth.errors, чтобы понять, это форма не возвращает ошибок, или шаблон не выводит их.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m2hob5pk/1/

Comment: С шаблоном все в порядке. Посмотрите исправленный код, первым аргументом в форму теперь передается request.

Comment: все заработало. огромное спасибо! долго не мог понять, в чем проблема

Comment: Не за что :) В случаях, когда приложение ведет себя не так, как ожидалось, помогает чтение исходников https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L170